# Where does the manga Otoyomegatari take place?

Tags: tourism, a-brides-story

I know it's located near the Middle East, but I'd like a more precise idea of the locations involved in Otoyomegatari.

Comment: I think it in Turkey.

Comment: @swswsws Mr. Smith and his guide is the one bound for Turkey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not already aware, the series is set in 19th century Central Asia. The culture is without a doubt Turkic.

The main setting of the story is explicitly mentioned to be a rural village near the Caspian Sea.

[image: Modern Day Central Asia]

It's important to note that the land and territory borders in the 19th century were [vastly different](http://www.britannica.com/topic/history-of-Central-Asia) from what is is today.

[image: Who are these ppl]

This bit, done by the author for the 2014 [Taisho Award](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga_Taish%C5%8D), sheds some light on the regions each of the characters are from.

Karluk's town (Pariya included) is located in modern Uzbekistan, and are of [Uyghur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uyghurs) ethnicity.

The city where Mr. Smith meets Talas, Karaza is likely in [Karakalpakstan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karakalpakstan), part of Uzbekistan.

The town where Mr. Smith and his guide meets the twins (Laila and Leyli, they're [Tajik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tajiks). Not Turkic, but rather Persian) is [Muynak/Moynaq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mo%E2%80%98ynoq), a city in northern Karakalpakstan.

Amir and her family are of [Kazakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazakhs) ethnicity, and hail from modern day Kazakhstan.

Comment: Awesome answer, the specific locations where really what I was looking for!